# save many records to couchdb in nodejs

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I have a [very large dataset](https://blog.skullsecurity.org/2010/return-of-the-facebook-snatchers) that I want to save in couchdb for searchability.

I want the records to look like this:

```
{
  "type": "first",
  "name": "ryan",
  "count": 447980
}
```

Since the text-files are larger than I should hold in memory, I am setting up a streaming readline reader, like so:

```
var db = require('./db'),
    readline = require('readline'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs');

// simple callback after cradle save
function saveHandler(er, doc){
    if (er) return console.log('Error: ', er);
    console.log(doc);
}

// save record of type, based on line with count & name
function handleCountedLine(type, line){
    return function(line){
        var record = {type:type};
        var i = line.trim().split(' ');
        record.name = i[1].trim();
        record.count = Number(i[0]);
        db.save(record, saveHandler);
    }
}

var handleFirst = handleCountedLine('first');
readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('data/facebook-firstnames-withcount.txt'),
    terminal: false
})
.on('line', handleFirst);
```

db is a cradle db.

After 40 records or so, it slows to a total crawl, then eventually runs out of memory. I tried [poolr](https://github.com/codingforce/poolr) and [node-rate-limiter](https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter), using "only run this many at a time" & "only allow this many to run in a minute" strategies. Both work a little better,  but it still runs out of memory. Is there a good way to accomplish this goal, or am I stuck [writing it in python](https://github.com/konsumer/couchfb/blob/master/import.py)?

Comment: Paulo Machado in google hangouts mentioned that I should pause & resume to throttle, which I wasn't aware I could do. I made this, and it handled 60 records (better but still not solved) before stalling: https://gist.github.com/konsumer/6d4003a6ff49c78c8a59

Comment: combining this with poolr got it up to 495 records before "process out of memory" https://gist.github.com/konsumer/6d24b8cdd3f353ddc0fa

Comment: I would not use readline. It will slow you down.

Comment: I did it without readline (using a custom stream) and it was a bit slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awesome help from Paulo Machado in google hangouts, I made an answer using [line-by-line](https://github.com/RustyMarvin/line-by-line), a simple wrapper that uses stream.pause() & stream.resume() to  only allow a single line to  be processed at a time. I'd like to give him the credit, but he hasn't come over here to make an answer, so I will just put this here. It has parsed 34039 records, so far. I will update the answer if it crashes.

```
var LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line'),
  path = require('path'),
  db = require('./db')

// line-by-line read file, turn into a couch record
function processFile(type){
  var fname = path.join('data', types[type] + '.txt');
  var lr = new LineByLineReader(fname, {skipEmptyLines: true});

  lr.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Error:');
    console.log(err);
  });

  lr.on('record', function (record) {
    console.log('Saved:');
    console.log(record);
  });

  lr.on('line', function (line) {
    lr.pause();
    var record = { type: type };

    if (type == 'full'){
      record.name = line.trim().split(' ');
    }else{
      var i = line.trim().split(' ');
      record.name = i[1].trim();
      record.count = Number(i[0]);
    }

    db.save(record, function(er, res){
      if (er) lr.emit('error', er, record);
      if (res) lr.emit('record', record);
      lr.resume();
    })
  });
}

var types = {
  'first':'facebook-firstnames-withcount',
  'last':'facebook-lastnames-withcount',
  'full':'facebook-names-unique'
};

for (type in types){
  processFile(type);
}

// views for looking things up
db.save('_design/views', require('./views'));
```

Comment: still chugging away at about 95,000 records!

Answer (score -1):

I guess couchdb is the bottleneck here. Have a look at [couchdb's bulk doc api](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-bulk-docs) that allows you to insert documents en masse. (You should probably not try to commit all your data at once, but accumulate a bunch of docs in an array and push that to the database -- use stream.pause() and stream.resume() to throttle the text stream). You will be rewarded with [efficiency gains by couchdb](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/database/bulk-api.html#inserting-documents-in-bulk) if you use the bulk api.

Comment: With the bulk doc API, it also runs out of memory (it requires you to load an array of records you want to update.)

Comment: As you (or rather Paulo Machado) mentioned in your comment above, you still need to throttle the stream. Edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but my point is that it's not the the bulk API that solves the question, it's line-by-line, and it's pausing of the read-stream (not just the readline stream, as I also tried.) Since the alternative for me is just to make a blocking script in python, I'm not as concerned with the performance gains of using intermittent arrays & the bulk API, especially considering that in the example above, it's still about 3 times as fast as the python equivalent (there are 3 concurrent streams, 1 for each file.)

Comment: The extra code it would take to manage interim arrays & and checks for the state of the queue are actually less desirable to me than the overhead of calling multiple HTTP requests for the records. This also lends itself to a more modular pattern, if I need to inject other munging of things in the stream.

Comment: You might think about using multiple node processes to abstract your modularity requirements, passing a file name and type to your script.  Note, though, that these requirements are not part of your original question. On the other hand, if speed is of concern to you, the bulk doc api is the way to go (the [couchdb definitve guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/performance.html#inserts) claims bulk insert speeds of about 2,700 docs/sec; in case of multiple processes over 3,600 docs/sec on a <2010 mac book pro). An amount of 95,000 records would have been inserted within half a minute.

Comment: That is awesome, and definitely an important consideration.  My question was more about how to actually throttle requests, though, not how increase efficiency. For a final solution, it would probably be a good idea to insert a stream munger that queued up records as bulk arrays, but your answer also does not have this sort of info. For things like this, I have been playing with [event-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream) to accomplish neat lil munging filters that are also pause & resumable.