# Running out of memory when using node streams

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, elasticsearch, stream

I am trying to index a big (1 500 000 lines) file and push it to elastic search. In order to do this, I am using node js streams; however, I keep running out of memory. What am I doing wrong?

```
var rl = null;

initialize(function() {
  var stream =  fs.createReadStream(process.argv[2]);
  rl = readline.createInterface({input: stream, terminal: false});
  var i = 0;

  rl.on('line', function(line) {
    rl.pause();
    processObject(++i, extractObject(line));
  });

  rl.on('close', function() {
    console.log('\nRefreshed index;');
    process.exit();
  });
});

function processObject(number, input) {
    client.index({
            index: INDEX,
            type: TYPE,
            id: number,
            body: input
    }, function (error, response) {
        rl.resume();
        if(number % 1000 == 0) process.stdout.write('.');
    });
};
```

Comment: Is your process throwing an error? Is the kernel panicking? I wouldn't say its a memory leak. Memory leaks are very uncommon, and typically only occur if there is a bug in the JS engine or in a native module.

Comment: the os is killing my process, saying that it ran out of memory.. i also tried to throttle it by limiting the number of insertions to 1000, but it still doesn't cut it...

Comment: Seems someone else had a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593251/save-many-records-to-couchdb-in-nodejs) inserting documents into couchdb. Also using readline module. Perhaps an issue with readline?

Comment: Also why don't you resume on callback like so: http://pastebin.com/QDpnXfSR

Comment: @tsturzl that was exactly the problem (see answer below). Thanks for the hint! :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so here is the solution. The code I wrote was just fine; the problem was with the 'readline' package. In fact, the rl.pause() function was not pausing the line reads, as it should. I solved it by switching to the 'line-by-line' package, which works in the same way. Using the same code, the process runs within 60 MB.

Comment: I've dealt with indexing large volumes of documents into elasticsearch before. You can likely achieve faster indexing if you buffer, let say 500 documents, and bulk index them. Rather than one request for every document.

Comment: agree :) that's what is going to come next!